# Java string.split() convention

Tags: java, string, split, conventions

I'm using the following line of code in my program to get the first part of a string.

```
struct.trailing.split(" ")[0]
```

For example, the string "Dogs and cats" would return "Dogs" with this line of code.  Is what I wrote convention? I tried this at random and it worked, piquing my curiosity,

Comment: Try: "*there is a whitespace before the text" (replace * with whitespace)

Comment: Yes, that's common shorthand when you only care about a certain token (usually the first or the second).

Comment: ...and you know `trailing` to be non-null.

Comment: The string is trim()ed before reaching this line of code so I don't need to worry about the leading/trailing whitespaces. Thanks all, this is a convention I didn't know before!

Comment: I'd not call it "convention" but rather a well known trick.

Answer (score 0):

[`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) also can be used
`StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, " ");`
 do the same.

Comment: except that it's advised to not use it, as per the official documentation "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead. "

Comment: Yes but there is a possibility to use it. I gave only an example.